# sum product of two columns in powerbi table with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to get the sum product of this table:

[image]

example: (0*.0256) + (1*.0468) + (2*.0344) ...

days to departure is a dimension under one table. And Conversions is a measure that I'm showing as % of Grand Total.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have table T with the column [Days To Departure] and the measure [%GT Conversions]

We want a measure to sum all the values of [%GT Conversions] for all the rows of T.

Let's call this measure [Total Formula], since I don't know what it'd be expected to represent

```
Total Formula = 
VAR Total = SUMX( ALL( T ), T[Conversion] )
RETURN
SUMX( ALL( T ), T[Days To Departure] * T[Conversion] / Total )
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help. I don't actually have %GT Conversions. That is made by clicking the drop down in the values field and showing values as percentage of grand total. when i try to use it in dax its not actually there. just [conversions] is there.

Comment: I changed the formula to compute the % from Conversion :)